# Rotation Problem

Tags: android

My android application has two imagebuttons side by side of equal lenght. They fill a line.
I turn my phone but imagebuttons is not filling the line.
Even if the phone rotate How do I displaying correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the weight property of the linear layout. Put both the button in a liner layout, specify layout_width = odp and weight=1 for both the button. The weight elements allows you to specify  the ratio of the width each element will take . Here is a sample

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
  </Button>
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: the sample is for a button , but you can use it for an image button too

Comment: I dont mean to sound rude but when an answer is useful/correct you need to accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the buttons in TableRow & check *after* rotation if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have width set to "fill_parent" and the weights adjusted correctly if you are using horizontal layout.

You can also, in onCreate, set the width of the image buttons manually.